# Visual C# ComboBox Dropdown Width

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, combobox

I am building a C# Windows Forms application (not WPF) on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2010.
My application contains a ComboBox.
I want to display a list of codes and descriptions.
I want the drop-down list to display both the code and the description, but I want the selected item in the text box to display just the code.
I want the dropdown list to be wider than the text box as shown in this [image](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC725271.png).
I want the dropdown list to display different data to the text box, as shown in this [image](https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC725272.png) - only instead of the icon, the relevant code will be displayed, where each code consists of a single, uppercase letter.
I'm guessing that I need a combination of the [ComboBox] properties *DisplayMember*, *ValueMember* and possibly *DropDownWidth* as well as a handler for the *SelectedIndexChanged* event. Correct?
Oh yes, in order to use the *DisplayMember* and *ValueMember* properties, I also need to use the *DataSource* property. Right?

Thanks,
Avi.

Comment: ... and what have you achieved so far? Can you share?

Comment: Ended up solving it via a custom class that had two properties which served as the _DisplayMember_ and _ValueMember_ properties. Then created a collection of instances of the custom class which served as the _DataSource_ property. Finally used the _DropDownWidth_ property to make the drop-down list wide and set a narrow text field width. Thanks to all who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a delimiter while setting values to ComboBox i.e. `"This is value => this is description"` in this string, `=>` is a delimiter, you can split this value based on this delimiter to display either first or last part of your item.

Answer (score 0):

Make class with data that will be shown as `ComboBox` items and override its `ToString()` method, something like this:

```
public class ComboItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

then, fill your combo box with items, in `page load` event in example,

```
ComboItem ci = new ComboItem() { ID = 1, Text = "code number 1", Description = "Description of item number 1" };
comboBox1.Items.Add(ci);
ci = new ComboItem() { ID = 2, Text = "code number 2", Description = "Description of item number 2" };
comboBox1.Items.Add(ci);
```

Extract description when needed (ie, when user selects something from your combobox):

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboItem ci = comboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboItem;
    string description = ci.Description; //here's your description
}
```